# is there a way to print aws internal loadbalancer dns from bastion host to cloudformation output section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am running aws eks cloudformation with bastion host, deploying required charts in bastion host and using internal loadbalancer to commuincate with k8s service.

The problem is, I can't use internal loadbalancer dns in cloudformation output section.

Is there a way to retrieve loadbalancer using fn::sub to cloudformation output section

Comment: Can you show any example template demonstrating your problem?

Comment: With [AWS Lambda-backed custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) you can do almost anything. May be oversized for your problem, the latter we do not really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if i got your question right. But you can retrieve a load balancers DNS name with `!GetAtt myLB.DNSName`...

```
Outputs:
  LbDnsName:
    Value: !GetAtt myLB.DNSName
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values